# JS Function for Multiple Links

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with several links, and each link needs to open in a new, resized window.

Here is how I am doing it for a single link with an inline script:

```
<h4 style="text-align: left;">
  <span style="font-size: x-large;">
    <a title="Link Title" href="#" target="popup" onclick="window.open('#','popup','width=800,height=400'); return false;" rel="noopener">Link Text</a>
  </span>
</h4>
```

I would like to avoid doing this for each link, and instead have a single function that can be used to open all specified links in a new resized window.

I'm a little stuck on how to accomplish this. Any directions or thoughts on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more code on how you're implementing this? Is this hard-coded HTML? Are you generating it via JS?

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like:

```
function openTab(linkTitle, url) {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.textContent = 'linkTitle'
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  // Add the below if you need it to open on call of function
  // link.click();
}
```

Then use like:

```
openTab("Title", "https://google.com");
```

Setting window size:

```
// This will get the first instance of a tag in your DOM
const getLink = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");
function openResizedTab(url) {
  window.open(url, "_blank","height=500,width=500");
}
openResizedTab(getLink)
```

Also follow this for rules you can add to window.open if you go down that route: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try and report back!